# Merge Single Excel Worksheet to one Workbook Using Python

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

I have a django site that will take uploaded .xls files and merge them into one Workbook

I am having trouble merging the uploaded the Worksdheets. Here is a sample of my code:

```
import pyexcel
import openpyxl
from pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            type_of_case = form.cleaned_data['Selection_type']
            case = form.cleaned_data['Case']
            new_name = type_of_case + '-' +case + '.xlsx'
            file_names = []
            objects=[]
            for x in request.FILES.getlist('Files'):
                filename = x.name
                file_names.append(filename)
                excel_ojects = x.read
                objects.append(excel_ojects)
                file_names.append(filename)
                print (x.content_type)
            merge_all_to_a_book(objects, outfilename=(new_name))
```

I've tried changing the merge_all_to_a_book to option (objects) and (file_names) but they both produce an error saying:
**OSError: Unsupported file type**

However when I print the content type I get:
    **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**

Can anyone help me to merge these freaking spreadsheets?

Comment: Can you simplify this and focus only on the code that merges the workbooks?  That would help isolate the issue: is it an issue with Excel, or Django, or something else?

Comment: It is for a Django project. Let me refocus my original post

Comment: It would be very useful if you included the full traceback.